# Order of a 2-level b+tree with n-distinct (assume e.g. n=10) entries

Tags: clustered-index, btree

Given a two-level clustered b+tree on a non-key attribute `foodCategory` (of which 10 distinct values exist), is it possible to calculate the order of the b+tree? Assuming an average 69% occupancy of nodes.

Furthermore, is it possible to generalize it to any number of n distinct values of `foodCategory`?

Would it be possible to estimate the order? That is, determine the range in which it is to be found?

Answer (score 3):

The order of a B-Tree (and its various derivations, B+, B-link etc.) is the maximum possible number of child nodes. Since yours is a two-level tree calculating the order is the same as calculating the maximum possible number of leaf nodes. Since you don't tell us the node size or key size the answer is "no, this is not possible."

> Would it be possible to estimate the order? That is, determine the range in which it is to be found?

Trivially, the lower limit is 2. Any fewer and there'd be no point in having an index. The upper limit would be less than (page size) / ((key size) + (pointer size)). "Less than" because there will be some overhead per page. Each DBMS will also have optimizations which others may not - key  compression, for example, or representation of non-unique values. If you're using MVCC or similar that will have its own overhead.